# How to hide an option in a dropdown using jquery?

Tags: jquery, dropdown, html-select

We are populating the options in a dropdown through list.The values are added in a list in Action class.
When option is equal to a particular value , we want to hide it.

Following is the code:

```
if (stuval.substring(0, 7) == "<option") {  
   $('#stuclass option:not(:first)').remove(); 
   $('#stuclass').find('option').end().append($(stuval));
   $("#stuclass option[value='not apply']").css("display", "none"); // Not working
}
```

How to hide the option when value is 'Not apply'?Tried with above code and using index.But it is not working.Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be a white-spaces, lower/uppercase in a value prevent it from the selection .. Some ways

1- Use `*` means contains `[value*='not apply']` in this way you need to take-care about lowercase and upper case and use the exact value .. if its `Not Apply` you've to use `[value*='Not Apply']`

```css
#stuclass option[value*="not apply"]{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="stuclass">
  <option value="apply">Apply</option>
  <option value= "not apply">Not Apply</option>
</select>
```

2- Use `.filter()` with `toLowerCase()` and `.trim()` .. I think this way is more efficient than the first one

```js
$('#stuclass option').filter(function(){
  return $(this).val().toLowerCase().trim() == 'not apply'
}).hide(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="stuclass">
  <option value="apply">Apply</option>
  <option value= "not apply">Not Apply</option>
</select>
```

Beside note:

- `.end()` here `$('#stuclass').find('option').end().append($(stuval));` will return to `$('#stuclass')` so you can directly use `$('#stuclass').append($(stuval))`
- Also `if (stuval.substring(0, 7) == "<option")` it will be better to be `if (stuval.trim().substring(0, 7) == "<option")` to avoid any left/right white-spaces OR you can use `if(stuval.indexOf('<option') > -1)`

For the select2

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').select2();
});
```

```css
.select2-results [data-select2-id*="not apply"]{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<select id="stuclass">
  <option value="apply">Apply</option>
  <option value= "not apply">Not Apply</option>
</select>
```

To hide the options from some of the select2 it can't be done by using css you can use javascript to remove the not apply option before append the select2 to the select you want

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#stuclass , #stuclass3').find('[value*="not apply"]').remove();
  $('select').select2();
});
```

```css
.select2{
  min-width : 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<select id="stuclass">
  <option value="apply">Apply</option>
  <option value= "not apply">Not Apply</option>
</select>

<select id="stuclass2">
  <option value="apply">Apply 2</option>
  <option value= "not apply">Not Apply 2</option>
</select>

<select id="stuclass3">
  <option value="apply">Apply 3</option>
  <option value= "not apply">Not Apply 3</option>
</select>

<select id="stuclass4">
  <option value="apply">Apply 4</option>
  <option value= "not apply">Not Apply 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: We use Jquery 1.10.4. Unfortunately this doesnt work. Used exactly the syntax what you had mentioned. Dont know where the mistake is.  Can you please help?

Comment: @Padmaja there is a big difference between option value and option text in your question you were asking about option value .. if you asking about text so use `return $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim() == 'not apply';`

Comment: Problem is we use select2 plugin in the dropdown..thats y it is not working....using normal select it is working fine....How to hide an option using select2 plugin in the dropdown?Kindly help...

Comment: @Padmaja answer updated .. check if this way will work for you or not

Comment: Hi...Have one more requirement....Want this 'not apply'  option to be hidden for that dropdown with that particular id..As we have that particular option in other dropdowns in that page...Please let me know how to do it?

Comment: @Padmaja Are you using css or js to hide the option?? if its css it should work for all `not apply` options on the page

Comment: Using CSS hence all options on the page are hidden..select2-results [data-select2-id*="not apply"]{
  display : none;
}
How to hide this option for that particular dropdown based on styleid?

Comment: The option shouldn't be removed or disabled.It should be hidden for that particular dropdown.Can we achieve that?

Comment: @Padmaja I tried a lot of things by using css and `select2-loaded` and `select2:open` events but none of them worked .. Sorry .. You can post this as a new question may be someone has a solution .. good luck